# Whitespaces not ignored in antlr3 grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am writing a simple antlr3 grammar to parse `hello world number` format.
Whitespaces are not being ignored between hello or world or number.

```
fragment H_ : 'h' | 'H';
.. 
fragment W_ : 'w' | 'W';

HELLO : H_ E_ L_ L_ O_ ;
WORLD : W_ O_ R_ L_ D_ ;
SEMI : ';';

INTEGER_NUM : ('0'..'9')+;
WS : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n') {$channel = HIDDEN;};

number : INTEGER_NUM;
hello : HELLO;
world : WORLD;
start[std::string& text] returns [int count] :
     hello world number EOF
     {$text = $hello.text;$text += $world.text;$count=std::stoi($number.text);};
```

I/p like 'helloworld5', '  helloworld5 ' are parsed fine.
But, 'hello world5', 'hello world 4' etc. doesn't.

Can anyone help, what am I missing here. Why are the Whitespaces b/w hello world not ignored?

Comment: Have you found the issue yet? I don't think your grammar is wrong, I created a test case myself in Java based on your example, and here it parses every input correctly. If you are still stuck, could you post more info like the full grammar syntax and the error message you're getting?